# Understanding why group by query slows down when there are lots of text columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query which runs slowly, I've come up with a much faster alternative, but I'd like some help understanding why the original query is so slow.

A simplified version of my problem use two tables. A simplified version of the first table, called profiles, is

```
`profiles` (
 `id` int(11),
 `title` char(255),
 `body` text,
 `pin` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pin` (`pin`)
 )
```

The simplified version of my second table, calls, is

```
`calls` (
 `id` int(11),
 `pin` int(11),
 `duration` int(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `ivr_id` (`pin`)
)
```

My query is supposed to get the full profiles, with the addition of the number of calls received by a profile. The query I was using, was

```
SELECT profiles.*, COUNT(*) AS num_calls 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN calls 
ON profiles.pin = calls.pin
GROUP BY profiles.pin
```

With ~100 profiles and ~250,000 calls, this query takes about 10 seconds which is slow.

If I modify the query to just select the title from profiles, not all columns, the query is much faster. If I modify the query to remove the group by, its also much faster. If I just select everything from the profiles table, then its also a fast query.

My actual profile table has many more text and char fields. The query speed is worse the more text fields that are selected. Why are the text fields causing the query to be so slow, when they are not involved in the JOIN or the GROUP?

I came up with a slightly different query which is much faster, less than half a second. This query is:

```
SELECT profiles.*, temp.readings 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pin ,COUNT(*) AS readings 
    FROM calls 
    GROUP BY pin
) AS temp 
ON temp.pin=profiles.pin
```

Whilst I think I've solved by speed problem, I'd like to understand what is causing the issue in the first query.

======== Update ========

I've just profiled both the queries and the entire speed difference is in the 'sending data' section. The slow query is about 10 seconds and the faster query is about 0.1 seconds

======== Update 2 ========

After discussing with @scaisEdge, I think I can rephrase my question. Consider a table T1 that has ~40 columns of which 8 are of type TEXT and ~100 rows and table T2 which has 5 columns of type INT and VARCHAR with ~250,000 rows. Why is it that:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM T1 is fast

SELECT T1.* FROM T1 JOIN T2 GROUP BY T1.joinfield is slow
```

`SELECT T1.selectfield FROM T1 JOIN T2 GROUP BY T1.joinfield` is fast if selectfield is an INT or VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

This should happpend  because

The first query   join  100 profile  with 250,000 calls  and then reduce the returning rows  grouping by the result . And the select profile.* implies the full accessing for each matching row to the profile table data

Then second query   join 100  profile  with the number of rows  returned  by subquery for TEMP  (problably much less than 250,000) reducing the number of  the access to the table profile data

Instead of   profile.* try  accessing only to pin column

```
SELECT profiles.pin, COUNT(*) AS num_calls 
FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN calls ON profiles.pin = calls.pin
GROUP BY profiles.pin
```

As a suggestion you should take note that use of group by for the first query   is allowed only for mysql version  earlier than version 5.7  .. because the use of group by column without mention column in select clause and not affected  by aggregation function and not mention  in GROUP BY is not allowed by defualt and produce error  ..

Comment: The part of your answer I don't understand is the 'full accessing'. Why does it matter how many of the columns of the profiles table I'm accessing? When MySQL does the join, is it creating a temporary table with full copies of all the data from the profiles?

Comment: 1) when  you use  select table.*  all the values  of the columns must be retrived  for populate the select result  .. so  for the columns value stored  in the index used in the specific query the values are retrived  directly .. for the others values  these values are fecthed  in the table data  .. so do the fact you are select all the columns  .. then all these values must be retrieved  acessing  each time to the table data ..

Comment: 2)  not exactly . when mysql perform a join (without invoking a sibquery) the db engine create internal reference for retrive the needed info .. when the engine has created the necessary references it performs fectching the data either from the index or from the table or from both ..hope this is clear ..

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. If the internal join is just using a reference, then why does a table.* query take so much longer as the data is not being copied multiple times? I'll update my question with a better explanation.

Comment: Because  the values for each column must be retrived  from the table  ..  more columns  more rows you have more time you consume  ..  if you have these value in the index these are not retrieved from the table  ..

Comment: Please can you take a look at my question update? Why is it fast to SELECT table.* without the JOIN and GROUP BY? You're still selecting all rows from the table.

Comment: If you do just a SELECT table.* just from the 'wide' table its fast, but if you do a SELECT table.* from the JOIN of the wide table with a table with a lot of records its slow. If the DB engine uses references for the JOIN why the difference in speed? There are the same number of records in both result sets. The cartesian product of the join will be very large, but if only dealing with references then why the slow down?

Comment: The number of records  is not the same   a single select and a select with join  involve  different numbers of rows.   for single table are involved  only the numbers of rows  of the single table ..but in a join are involed  table1xtable2  row and (using the columns for join) are showed only the valid rows ..  if there index  valid for the join this is pretty fast if not or if not all the columns are contained  in  index  this is slow ..  remember that a relation (a join) involve ever  table1_row_num  multiplied  by table_ruw_num  rows ..